# How to populate a dynamic form by key name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Building a page with multiple forms but I cant seem to get the populatie to work. As I want to match the value by key but it is not working.

```
// template part
<form v-for="(questions, index) in data">
    <div v-for="(question, index2) in questions">
        <input type="text" v-model="forms[index+'-'+index2]"/>
    </div>
</form>

// js code

data: function () {
    return {
      forms [],
    }
}, 
mounted () {
   this.setForm();
},
methods: {
  setForm() {
    for (let question = 0; question < this.questions.length; ++question) {
        for (let user = 0; user < this.users.length; ++user) {
            this.forms[user+'-'+question] = this.getPoints(user, question)// getPoints does return a single value
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I made and edit

Comment: another question, where do you run that for loop?

Comment: build in the methods fn and run in the mounted fn

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@input` event and `value` attribute instead of `v-model` :

```html
<form v-for="(questions, index) in data">
    <div v-for="(question, index2) in questions">
        <input type="text" @input="($event)=>onInput($event.target.value,index,index2)" :value="forms[index+'-'+index2]"/>
    </div>
</form>

<script>

data: function () {
    return {
      forms [],
    }
}, 
mounted () {
   this.setForm();
},
methods: {
  onInput(val,index,index2){
   this.$set(this.forms,index+'_'+'index2',val)
 },
  setForm() {
    for (let question = 0; question < this.questions.length; ++question) {
        for (let user = 0; user < this.users.length; ++user) {
            this.forms[user+'-'+question] = this.getPoints(user, question)// getPoints does return a single value
        }
    }
   }
}
</script>
```